# Input between multiline strings python3

Tags: python-3.x, string, input

Well, you see, I have searched and searched without any results on how to make an input between multiline strings, such as something like this:

```py
print("******************************\nPassword: ", end="")
x = input()
print("******************************")
print("Your password is %s" % (x))
```

( but when i do this, the last of asterisks line is not printed until the input has be done )

or also like in GNU nano, when you write text you do it between strings with new lines

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

I get it, you have to do a return (\r) and then a backspace (\b), here is my program that prompts for the password and a function to make it easier.

Password prompt program:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from readchar import readchar
from os import get_terminal_size
from sys import stdout

print("\n"*((get_terminal_size()[1]-5)//2))

spaces = " " * ((get_terminal_size()[0]-53)//2)
passwd = ""

text = ""
text+="\r\b\r\b\r\b "
text+="""{0}#####################################################\n"""
text+="""{0}#                                                   #\n"""
text+="""{0}#    Password:                                      #\n"""
text+="""{0}#                                                   #\n"""
text+="""{0}#####################################################\n"""
text+="""\r\b\r\b\r\b\r"""
text+="""{0}#      Password: {1}"""

stdout.write(text.format(spaces, "*" * len(passwd)))
stdout.flush()


try:
    ch = readchar()

    while ch != "\n":

        if ch == "\x7f":
            passwd = passwd[:-1]

        elif ch in ["\r", "\x03"]:
            break

        else:
            passwd += ch


        if len(passwd) > 32:
            stdout.write(text % ("*"*32))

        else:
            stdout.write(text.format(spaces, "*" * len(passwd)))


        stdout.flush()


        ch = readchar()

except(KeyboardInterrupt):

    pass


print("\n"*5+passwd )
```

Function:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def backspace_enter(charlen, get_back=False):
    print("\r\b"*charlen, end="")

    if get_back == True:
        print("\n"*charlen, end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are dealing with buffering issues on stdout.   Add flush =true to your print statement.

```
print("Hello\n", flush=True);
```